# What is the wp_profile Administrative Console URL of IBM Portal Express 8.5?

Tags: websphere-portal

I was just exploring Portal Express 8.5 and was able to login to the admin console of cw_profile but not to the wp_profile. In Portal express 8 version we can use https://:10032/ibm/console/logon.jsp. This is not working on 8.5 version.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the ports are assigned during installation, so it could be that they vary depending what is already installed on your system. You can check the config on the server itself by checking serverindex.xml. The file is located at *wp_profile/config/cells//nodes/*

Inside of this file you can check for **WC_adminhost** and **WC_adminhost_secured**. These two elements provide you information on the port used for the admin console.

The file I checked had them like this

```
<specialEndpoints xmi:id="NamedEndPoint_1430250971397" endPointName="WC_defaulthost">
<endPoint xmi:id="EndPoint_1430250971397" host="*" port="10039"/>
</specialEndpoints>
...
<specialEndpoints xmi:id="NamedEndPoint_1430250971399" endPointName="WC_adminhost_secure">
<endPoint xmi:id="EndPoint_1430250971399" host="*" port="10032"/>
</specialEndpoints>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot stefan, i got the console. Portal 8.5 __WC_adminhost__ port is 10038 and __WC_adminhostsecure__ port is 10041. In Portal 8 __WC_adminhost__ port is 10042 and __WC_adminhostsecure__ port is 10032.